# Single Stylesheet Multiple Pages Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: css, stylesheet, dreamweaver

I have 2 pages that share the same stylesheet. How do I make changes to one, without affecting the other? I am new to coding, so please be specific as possible.

For Instance: I have a main image on the HOME page and want to delete it on the PRACTICE AREAS page but whenever I do so it deletes it on all pages.

Help please, and thank you in advance!

Comment: Always try to show *what you have already tried*. Posting code helps people understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice for styling pages differently is to have a class name applied to the body or to the enclosing div which corresponds to the page, e.g.:

```
<body class="home">
  <div>Content here</div>
</body>
```

This gives you greater specificity, so in your CSS, you could be writing:

```
.home div {
  background-image: url('your-image.jpg') no-repeat left top;
}
```

... or some such.

But, it sounds like the image on your home page is **content**, rather than its presentation. In that case you should be including it in the HTML rather than the CSS.

```
<body class="home">
  <div><img src="your-image.jpg"> Content here</div>
</body>
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not do conditionals with CSS.  I suggest you create a second style sheet for your "Practice Areas" page and simply override the style element showing the main image.  For example

/* On main style sheet */


`body 
{ 
  background-image: url(../graphics/main_page.jpg);
}`

/* On Practice Areas style sheet: */

body
{
  background-image: none;
}